# php if elseif else for search results, no results, empty search. I can't get the elseif to apply

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
<?php if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) : ?>
    <h2 class="black">
    <?php
    echo sprintf( __( '%s Search Results for ', 'html5blank' ), $wp_query->found_posts );
    echo get_search_query();
    ?>
    </h2>
<?php elseif ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) == null ) : ?>
    <h2 class="red">
    <?php
    echo sprintf( __( '%s Search Results for ', 'html5blank' ), $wp_query->found_posts );
    echo get_search_query();
    ?>
    </h2>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="empty">Search <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'theme_options_name', '' ); ?></h2>
<?php endif ?>
```

I cant get the elseif to turn red when no results are returned.

`www.site.com/?s=hello`

the first is a search that returns posts, this is black 
the second is a search that returns no posts, this should be red 
the third is an empty search, this is black.

Comment: `isset` always returns true or false, it never returns null - take a look at the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php. So `isset($_GET['s'])==null)` makes no sense. Perhaps you intended to check for `false` there? But that would simply require an `else`, there's no need to run isset() twice. So that deals with whether a search was specified or not. Now _within_ the `if (isset(...` block, you need another `if` after the query has run, to see if there were any results or not.

Comment: ok, what would be most helpful, as I am new to php, is exactly what you would replace that line of code with. I know it is wrong, that is why I am here but I haven't been able to fix it after googling and reading other responses. HOW to I solve the no results search, I can't just to an else because that makes it default and doesn't account for an empty search

Comment: Like I said, the "no results" is solved by a second `if` _within_ the `if(isset($_GET['s']))`, _after_ you've actually done the search and can see how many rows it returned.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a lot of mistakes/typos in your code.

1. `echo` is `echoe`
2. `__()` function starting with double quotes `__("` but ending with single quote `')`
3. closing `</h2>` is wrong in the first two cases.

after fixing all those things, the code with your expected results will be like this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;

// Check is ?s is available in url and it's value is not empty.
if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {

    // check if don't have empty results.
    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->found_posts ) ) {
        ?>
        <h2 class="black"><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( __( '%1$s Search results found for %2$s', 'text-domain' ), $wp_query->found_posts, get_search_query() ) ); ?></h2>
        <?php
    } else {
        // if we have empty result.
        ?>
        <h2 class="red"><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( __( '%1$s Search results found for %2$s', 'text-domain' ), $wp_query->found_posts, get_search_query() ) ); ?></h2>
        <?php
    }
} else {
    // if ?s exists but empty.
    ?>
    <h2 class="empty"><?php echo esc_html( sprintf( __( 'Search %s', 'text-domain' ), get_theme_mod( 'theme_options_name', '' ) ) ); ?></h2>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I will try this. my code doesn't have typos in actual code but it is in another computer so I retyped not in a code editor. :) the problem with this approach is that it goes to the else in the nested if and never makes it to the empty search

Comment: I tried this in <?php elseif( empty( $wp_query->found_posts ) ): ?>
but still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Please use like below code:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] !=''): ?>
    <h2 class='black'> <?php echoe sprintf(__("%s Search Results for ',
     'html5blank'), $wp_query->found_posts ); echo get_search_query(); ?> <h2>
**<?php elseif(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] ==''): ?>
    <h2 class='red'> <?php echoe sprintf(__("%s Search Results for ',
     'html5blank'), $wp_query->found_posts ); echo get_search_query(); ?> <h2>**
<?php else: ?>
    <h2 class='empty'> Search <?php get_theme_mod('theme_options_name', ''); ?> </h2>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: thank you, this is still not turning red but the code is better